# Populating placeholders in a local resource file

Tags: c#, resource-files

I have the following text in a resource file.

```
Hello {{studentName}},
Your schedule is  ....
```

Is there a way to set the placeholder {{studentName}} to a given value, before loading the resource file?   I've done this with strings, but not a resource file.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "resource file". Resource (.res/.resx) files can contain text resources, or you can include an arbitrary file as a resource, load the resource data and convert it to a string for text manipulation, Or sometimes "resource files" can refer to a file on disk separate from the exe. I can't tell from your question what the structure of your application is, so you'll need to provide more precise information about what you're asking about.

Comment: I went through some of my old notes and found a solution.  It's an resx file: App_LocalResources\Contact.aspx.resx file.  My solution is in the edit

Comment: @Greg What about using `string.Format()` or a simple `Replace()` on the string?

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I feel dumb answering my own question, but here goes.

I just need to use the same formatting for strings.
Update the file to show

```
Hello {0},
Your schedule is  ....


string.Format((string)GetLocalResourceObject("ContactText"), "Mike");
```

Too obvious I guess ...